# Responsive Text overlay on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i have a image that let's say have a chat dialogue .

I want to overlay a div on top of the text, then i want put some text on the div.

When I rescale the browser smaller, the text should become smaller, but position remain same. vice versa the text become bigger when browser rescale bigger.

The div will likely be a background color and should also rescale just like the text.

I tried with

```
.herotext span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'museo_slab500';
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 40%;
    line-height: 150%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

But even though my text rescale when I rescale my browser, but my div which is white background doesn't rescale properly, and when browser turn smaller, the div doesn't rescale.

Any solution or idea for this implementation?

Comment: Can you show us the html code too please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "vw" in your text CSS to set the size of the text relative to the width of your device:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <span>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3fcczwb/1/